# Create Element pass propalong the component tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mixpanel

I have the challenge to implement a solution that works fine integrating react and mixpanel to track events. After searching a lot of solutions I followed one that I thought could fit the best on the project. This one: https://avi.io/blog/2016/08/31/scalable-and-generic-mixpanel-tracking-for-react-redux-applications/

What I need is to create a wrapper for all my component tree so I can access all components of the trackEvent prop.

**I created a wrapper around the app like this:**

```
  <MixpanelWrapper>
    <App />
  </MixpanelWrapper>
```

**MixpanelWrapper.js:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sendMixpanelEvent } from 'services/store/modules/mixpanel/mixpanel.actions.js';

const MIXPANEL = {
  EVENTNAME: 'data-mixpanel-eventname',
  PROPERTIES: 'data-mixpanel-properties',
};

const MixpanelWrapper = ({ children, track }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { trackEvent: track }));
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    track: e => {
      const target = e.target;
      const eventName = target.getAttribute(MIXPANEL.EVENTNAME);
      const eventAttributes = target.getAttribute(MIXPANEL.PROPERTIES);

      if (eventName && eventAttributes) {
        dispatch(sendMixpanelEvent(eventName, eventAttributes));
      }
    },
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MixpanelWrapper);
```

What I do here is cloning each child of the MixpanelWrapper and passing the prop trackEvent to it. But on this one I just have access to the trackEvent prop on the App file and not on all the other components.

How can I archive that solution? any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: you may also want to try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mixpanel

Comment: I already have a midleware implemented, that is what i don't want to do, have my application with mixpanel calls everywhere

Comment: do you have your mixpanel added to your root reducer?